# Loop within a loop within a loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, nested

I'm trying to run a batch. I need certain columns from one sheet copied and pasted into a newly created sheet. This should include name, email, etc. I have made a  nested loop in order to do that, but I can't stop the output row from incrementing after the data starts to repeat itself. It continues all the way down the page. My code is as follows:

'gather data

```
For r = 1 To ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Row
    Cells(1, c).Select
        Do Until IsEmpty(Selection)
        name = ActiveCell.End(xlToLeft).Value
        email = ActiveCell.End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Value
        phoneNumber = ActiveCell.End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 2).Value
        generation = ActiveCell.End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 3).Value
        status = ActiveCell.End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 13).Value

'paste data

        Sheets("Compiled Data").Select
        Cells(oRow, c) = name
        Cells(oRow, c + 1) = email
        Cells(oRow, c + 2) = phoneNumber
        Cells(oRow, c + 3) = generation
        Cells(oRow, c + 4) = status

        oRow = oRow + 1

        Loop
```

As you can see, I already have two loops running. I'm wondering if I need a third to stop the output (oRow) and if it's even possible to have a loop within a loop within a loop.

Thanks.

Comment: Move ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Row to a variable outside of loop

Comment: Your using "r" in loop counter but incrementing oRow

Comment: `Do Until IsEmpty(Selection)` you need to select a new cell if you're going to use that logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
Cells(1, c).Select
```

This always selects row 1. i don't think that's what you want.
Also switching between the sheets is very inefficiant. You have

```
Sheets("Compiled Data").Select
```

but you never switch back to your first sheet.

This should run smoother

```
c_old = 1 'Your "Name" column in original
c_new = 1 'Your "Name" column in Compiled Data

For r = 1 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, c_old).End(xlUp).Row
    For j = 0 To 3
        Sheets("Compiled Data").Cells(r, c_new + j) = Cells(r, c_old + j)
    Next j
    Sheets("Compiled Data").Cells(r, c_new + 4) = Cells(r, c_old + 13)
Next r
```